# C++, Libsodium, how encrypt and decrypt correctly a file

Tags: c++, encryption, libsodium

I try to encrypt and decrypt a file with the Libsodium Library, in particular I would like to use ChaCha20-Poly1305 algorithm.

I have seen this code in Libsodium documentation:

```
main(void)
{
    unsigned char key[crypto_secretstream_xchacha20poly1305_KEYBYTES];

    if (sodium_init() != 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    crypto_secretstream_xchacha20poly1305_keygen(key);
    if (encrypt("/tmp/encrypted", "/tmp/original", key) != 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (decrypt("/tmp/decrypted", "/tmp/encrypted", key) != 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can find the body of the encryption and decryption functions [here](https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/secret-key_cryptography/secretstream#file-encryption-example-code).

I have two questions:

1. Why the functions want only the **target file**, the **source file** and the **key**?, I mean why the functions don't request the **nonce** and the tag and how can i add **additional data** in the file?
2. Am I wrong if I manually read the contents of the file and encrypt it, so without using those functions that libsodium gives me?

Comment: *Am I wrong if I manually read the contents of the file and encrypt it* -- I do not know libsodium, but if you're suggesting you write your own encryption code, don't.  Leave that to the experts or libraries that focus on encryption.

Comment: Why: because it's an example